# getting length of nested array in mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

this is my mongodb collection

```json
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("654b585e7c92b812d783e7ac"),
    channel_id: 3,
    episode: {
      '1764': {
        likes: [ '654b163864213bbd6b183b26' ],
        comment: [ { '654b163864213bbd6b183b26': 'test1' } ],
        bookmarks: [ '654b163864213bbd6b183b26' ]
      }
    },
    channel_bookmark: [ '654b163864213bbd6b183b26', '654b9d4d74ecf78f19331deb' ]
  }
]
```

and this is my query:

```js
data = podcast_collection.find_one({"channel_id": channel_id, "channel_bookmark": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": [user_id]}}})
```

as you notice i check if an specific `user_id` exists in my collection but i want to get count of `"channel_bookmark"` item in my query at the same time.
how can i achieve that?

i thought i can get my count of `"channel_bookmark"` items with that query and i got that but only when that specific `user_id` is in `"channel_bookmark"`.

this is my query output when `user_id` exists in `"channel_bookmark"`:

```json
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("654b585e7c92b812d783e7ac"),
    "channel_id": 3,
    "episode": {
      "1764": {
        "likes": [
          "654b163864213bbd6b183b26"
        ],
        "comment": [
          {
            "654b163864213bbd6b183b26": "test1"
          }
        ],
        "bookmarks": [
          "654b163864213bbd6b183b26"
        ]
      }
    },
    "channel_bookmark": [
      "654b163864213bbd6b183b26",
      "654b9d4d74ecf78f19331deb"
    ]
  }
```

and i access the length of `"channel_bookmark"`.

but when the query output is none (when `user_id` does not exist in `"channel_bookmark"`) i cant get length of channel_bookmark

Comment: Use [$size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to get array length. Also, give expected output format for the case that query output is none.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but still doesn't work, here is my query:
`data = podcast_collection.find_one({"channel_id": channel_id, "channel_bookmark": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": [user_id]}}}, projection={"channel_bookmark": 1, "count": {"$size": "$channel_bookmark"}})`

Comment: What *doesn't work*? The result is not as expected? Again, you need to [edit] your question to include the expected output so people can take a closer look. Also, try out `$size` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JvNQv4yvvdI)

Comment: i mean it still gives me none as output when user_id in not in channel_bookmark.

Comment: [edit] your question to includ such an example and the corresponding expected output. Otherwise, your question will remain unclear and no one can help

Comment: If user_id is not in the bookmark array, the return value of find_one will be null, i.e. there will be no document, and therefore no fields.  The application code should be able to test for null and generate whatever default document you want to use, which can include `count:0` and whatever other fields you care to define.

Comment: @FarzamPilAghaee So, you want the `"$size"` of `"channel_bookmark"` regardless of its contents?  If so, there should be no matching condition (e.g., like `"channel_bookmark": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": [user_id]}}` as part of the query.

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks, i changed the query like this `podcast_collection.find_one({"channel_id": channel_id, "channel_bookmark": {"$exists": True}},projection={"channel_bookmark": {"$elemMatch": {"$in": [user_id]}},"count": {"$size": "$channel_bookmark"}})` and got what i want